# Pydot 'dot not found in path'

Tags: python, graphviz, pydot

I have checked the other questions on this problem, but my issue is a bit different.

I'm trying to plot a tree from random forest model using pydot. The module is correctly installed and there are no issues importing it, but when it comes to exporting the resulting plot as png I get an error that "dot" not found in path.

```py
# Use dot file to create a graph
(graph, ) = pydot.graph_from_dot_file('dot_files/rf_WB.dot')

#Write graph to a png file
graph.write_png('rf_WB.png')

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-17-baf03a7dd886>", line 5, in <module>
    graph.write_png('rf_WB.png')

  File "C:\Users\cherp2\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pydot.py", line 1922, in create
    raise OSError(*args)

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] "dot" not found in path.
```

The problem is that I have the path to `dot.exe` in my PATH (C:\ProgramData\Graphviz\release\bin):

[image]

I can also run dot directly from command prompt without issues. Anyone knows what could be causing this to happen?

I'm using Anaconda/Spyder and Python 3.6.

Comment: Can you create a basic example and run it outside Anaconda? Do you still get an error that way?

Comment: Tried creating a simple script and running from cmd, didn't work. At the same time running `dot -Tpng rf_WB.dot -o tree.png` works without issues.

Comment: check if dot is being found by typing `where dot` at the command prompt.